# Remove identical entries that have true value on a column in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table that kinda looks like this:

```
WebDocumentId   To remove
675082          0
675082          0
675082          0
675083          0
675083          1
675083          0
675083          0
675083          0
675085          1
675085          0
675087          0
675087          0
675087          1
675087          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
```

My aim is to somehow remove all the identical entries for which 1 appears at least once in the 'to remove' column. A simple VLOOKUP on a third column would have worked if 1 was the first value of an id.

Summing up, the final table should look like this:

```
WebDocumentId   To remove
675082          0
675082          0
675082          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if there's a `1` in "To Remove" column, you want to delete those? You could simply filter that column, showing only "0", then copy/paste visible cells. Or as you say use a formula that looks to see if the value is `0` and then if so, return the ID?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BruceWayne and Moderator Impersonator, you missed a key point.  Check the final table.  Only one representative record has a 1, but any record with the same DocID gets removed.

Comment: Are the duplicate IDs always contiguous, or can they be scattered throughout the records?  If the number of 1's is small, you could do this manually with a filter.  First find a 1, then filter on the associated value in the ID column.  Delete all of the results.  Rinse and repeat.  A more automated way would be to use a helper column.  Put a 1 there for every record where the ID matches an ID of a record with a 1 in the To Remove column.  Then use the helper column as the basis rather than the To Remove column.  VBA would also be a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in the third column the following formula:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$19=A2)*$B$2:$B$19)>0,"Delete","")`
and drag it down

A2:A19 is the column of `WebdocumentId` keep the `$` for absolute reference (fixed references)
B2:B19 is the column of 0,1... keep the `$` for fixed references
Sumproduct will result in the sum of column 0,1 if it has the same Id of the row the formula is in

```
If the sum =1 or >0 the If is True and will write `Delete`, if False will be empty
```

When finish you can copy paste special value of the third column in a column next to it and `Sort` the whole array by this new column `Descending`
Delete will be above all and you can select the rows and delete it.

```
Column A         Column B  Column C      Column D
  WebdocumentId  To remove Delete
    675082          0   =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$19=A2)*$B$2:$B$19)>0,"Delete","")
    675082          0   
    675082          0   
    675083          0    Delete
    675083          1    Delete
    675083          0    Delete
    675083          0    Delete
    675083          0    Delete
    675085          1    Delete
    675085          0    Delete
    675087          0    Delete
    675087          0    Delete
    675087          1    Delete
    675087          0    Delete
    675089          0   
    675089          0   
    675089          0   
    675089          0
```